# Reproducing raster color rendering from ArcMap in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, visualisation, rendering

I have a 16-bit satellite geotif. These images can be visualised in a number of ways, depending on which stretch you apply.

The default stretch applied by ArcGIS to these images produces a "natural" result, which is good.

However, when I view a raster (satellite geotif file) in QGIS, the color is very different than in ArcMap. The result is over-exposed and less "natural".

Can I maintain/replicate ArcGIS's color rendering / stretch for users viewing the satellite tifs in QGIS?

[image]

Comment: Can you show us what they look like in both systems? Or describe the difference better? Are they three-band RGB images?  Have you looked at the rendering style parameters in each system?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include screenshots and rendering settings in both software packages.

Comment: Done.

My understanding is that 16bit satellite geotiffs can be visualised a number of ways , depending on which stretch you apply. The default stretch/visualisation of my satellite geotiffs are great in ArcGIS, but in QGIS they are over-exposed. I want to share my data with users who do have access to ArcGIS, and can use QGIS, but would like the image's visualisation/stretch to be akin to ArcGIS.

Comment: We can't help unless you add more details.  We need the rendering settings as requested previously. What stretch is being applied by both packages? What are the image statistics? Have you tried applying the same stretch with the same statistics as used by ArcGIS in QGIS?

Comment: 1) Whether I use a single band or multi-band raster satellite image, the result is the same: ArcGIS and QGIS images are visualised differently. 2) The ArcGIS rendering settings are the following default: RGB Composite, Stretch = Percent. 3) The QGIS settings are the following default: render type = multiband color, blending mode = normal. 

4) My question states "can I replicate ArcGIS's stretch in QGIS", so no I haven't applied the same stretch as I do not know how to achieve this. If you do know how to apply the same stretch, please post instructions/an answer. Thank you.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to contain any clarifications. It's not fair to the volunteers who would help to need to review comments for critical information. You also have far more formatting options to make the question more legible than comments could ever be.

Comment: No, that's not all the rendering properties.  Can you provide screenshots of the ArcGIS properties, don't forget to scroll down and show the statistics section.